# How can I see what else is going on with Appengine Appstats

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working with a Java/Appengine project and can't figure out what is happening in between RPC calls within Appstats. There are long periods of time (sometimes > 1000ms) where I know the code is not doing anything significant in terms of CPU load, but are increasing response time considerably.

Could this be further RPC calls that are not showing in AppStats? Is there a way of isolating what is being done in these periods?

[image: AppStats]

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem before, the gap that I saw was about few seconds in the worst case. After talking to google support (they can see it from their side but we can't!) turned out what happened was the CPU isthrottled, and the solution was to use higher instance (f1 -> f2 in my case). Not sure if it helps in your case but maybe give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We moved to B2 instances which has helped a bit but not much. Still seeing the issue. Also seeing this occasionally running locally (!) so not sure what is going on there...Did moving to f2 instances fix the problem completely?

Comment: Hard to tell, can't check all the requests, but we have metric that calculate average latency for some endpoints, and it looks better after moving to F2